# Persist/store in domain or application layer?

Tags: domain-driven-design

When creating a new entity, should the application service layer persist/attach it to the entity manager, the domain service layer or can even domain objects do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point where the new entity is created, the code that creates the entity should also register the new entity with the unit of work for persisting at the successful completion of that unit of work.